# Dynamically Update Query Based on User ID

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, powerbi

Data are gathered from a SQL Server database.

When a user logs into the web app, I'd like for the queries to update based on that user's ID. So, something like the statement below where the "userid" value dynamically changes.

```
select * from table where userid = 1234
```

My initial thought was to use row level security, but since we have hundreds of users, setting up the individual role for each user seems like an inefficient process. I don't want to add the userid as a filter since a user could clear the filter and then see other user's information.

Passing the userid as part of a URL parameter would be ideal .

Has anyone come across this requirement before? Any thoughts or suggested solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: "Passing the userid as part of a URL parameter would be ideal." Maybe not - if I'm logged in as Alice and change the URL to `somethingSomething?userid=Bob` I'll be able to see Bob's records. Users can change things in Firefox/Chrome debugger just like you can for testing.

Comment: I agree, passing it in as part of the url is less than ideal, but there are ways to deal with that. That aside, and getting to the SQL question at hand, having dealt with this kind of thing before, we've used parameters in the SQL. `select fld1, fld2, fld3, fld4, fld5 from someTable where UserId = @UserID` The ID then comes from the security context, or through which ever security model we're using in that case, since it can vary from case to case.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning It won't make a problem because i'm using the iframe generated from the power bo into my angular app so the user can't touch the link and modify it

Comment: @TechGnome I will try this

Comment: @zarzou: Sure they can. The client can do *anything*. In a web browser, I can pop the dev tools and change anything I want on your site. No problem. *Never* assume the user can't do something.

Comment: @ChrisPratt Well you are right but in my case no problem if he can change it with teh devtools i want just it working and unchangeabel in the page .

Comment: That *is* changeable in the page. That's what the dev tools allow you to do.

Answer (score 0):

You should get the user id from the authenticated principal, and then pass that internally along to whatever query you're making. For example, in an ASP.NET Core controller action, you can do:

```
var userId = User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
```

Then, pass that value into the query as appropriate.